# A class used to save a file, saves it every time with a different name

Tags: java

I think that I have a quite strange question. I am using a class -in an already existing code-  that was primarily used to open a Save Dialog window. The code that was used is the below:

```
String savedName;


if (OperatingSystem.isMacOSX()) {
  savedName = showFileDialog(parentView, dialogTitle, contentType, name, true);
} else {
  savedName = showFileChooser(parentView, dialogTitle, contentType, name, true);
}
```

so what I did is to put it into block comment and now I would like to save the project, by using a different name every time that the class is called. This name will be taken from an array using this code:

```
int m = 0;

for (HomePieceOfFurniture piece : home.getFurniture()) {
  if (piece.isVisible()) {
         m++;
  } } // A table used to save the names of the furniture and initialize it
String [] Furniture = new String[m];   
m = 0;

for (HomePieceOfFurniture piece : home.getFurniture()) {
   if (piece.isVisible()) {
       // "a" is used to save the name of the furniture piece
       String a = piece.getName();
       Furniture[m] = a;
       //System.out.printf(Furniture[m]);
       m++;
       }
    }
```

What I want is a tip to find how I can understand how this class is called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How what class is called? If you want to call the original method (the first snippet) with a filename as a parameter, modify the method to accept an addition parameter called `savedName`, remove the declaration inside the method, and is the rest as-is.

Comment: The code you commented out doesn't save the file - it only allows the user the select a file location and name.

Comment: I think that you are quite right about that...I will try it:)

Comment: @Paul Yeah, what I want to do is to control the saved name and its location:)

Comment: Then @DaveNewton has the correct answer. You just need to set `savedName` to the value you want.

Comment: @DaveNewton Please write your answer, as an answer, so I could close the topic. Stupid question, really:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call the original method (the first snippet) with a filename as a parameter, modify the method to accept an addition parameter called savedName, remove the declaration inside the method, and leave the rest as-is.

```
public void someMethod(String savedName) {
    // The commented-out code that used to ask for a filename.
    // if (OperatingSystem.isMacOSX()) {
    //     savedName = showFileDialog(parentView, dialogTitle, contentType, name, true);
    // } else {
    //     savedName = showFileChooser(parentView, dialogTitle, contentType, name, true);
    // }

    // Rest of method stays the same.
    File f = new File(savedName);
    // etc.
}
```

Then call it from your new code that creates the filename.